# Error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ‘[String].Type’

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I’m very new in Swift and trying to use int values 0-10 in my UIPickerView but there’s some errors that I don’t really understand.

Here’s my code - I’m putting the UIPickerView inside a TextField I just thought it looked neater that way.

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var startPicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var endPicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    var pickerView = UIPickerView()
    
    var numbers = [String] = []
      
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        
        repeatTextField.inputView = pickerView
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        for i in 1..<10 {
            numbers.append(String(i))
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    internal func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(row + 1)
    }
}
```

This is where the error shows up:

```
var numbers = [String] = []
```

I can only rlly see tutorials of using UIPickerView with String but not Int.

This is what I’m trying to attain:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIEQM.png)

Could you please help me how to resolve this? Thanks in advance! :))

Comment: Simple typo: should be `var numbers : [String] = []`. You may wish to review the Swift book [chapter on properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

Comment: Oh wow that was silly! Thank you so much for your help. I was going crazy lol

Answer (score 0):

You can: `var numbers: [String] = []` or `var numbers = [String]()`